# How to send Push notification to iOS WebApp (PWA)?

Tags: ios, wordpress, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

i have wordpress website and create own PWA based on wordpress.

now i want to use push notification on my web app!

how can send push notification to my ios users?

[resolved in android pwa]

Comment: Only native apps can receive push notifications on iOS.

Comment: Any updates on this after ios 15.4 release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, push notifications are not yet available on IOS.

Right now, Safari only supports push notification on Mac.

If you want push notifications on IOS, you have to develop native app.

Comment: This is a highly unstable piece of tech--heads up, it looks like there is (extremely hamstrung, but existing) support, potentially, now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819485/sending-push-notifications-to-ios-from-pwa

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround,the [Wise Notifications plugin](https://wisenotifications.com/wordpress-plugin.html)

It takes 5 min to setup and the website visitors can subscribe with 2 taps maximum. It uses a notifications hub app to make it possible.

While not as easy to subscribe (if the visitors don't have the hub app already installed) as usual web push notifications, it is the only quick way to reach your iOS audience.

The alternative is for you to create a native/hybrid iOS applications, publish it to the AppStore, implement Apple Push Notifications in the app and server and send notifications via APNS (Apple Push Notification service). This requires a quite a lot of effort (time or money or both).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, push notifications are supported (not yet) on IOS.

Safari only is the only browser in IOS, others use webview (based on Safari) with just a UI.