# What is a reasonable alternative to push notifications for web apps on iOS that does not require a native app install?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

There are many questions about getting push notifications to work for web apps on iOS, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625015/push-notifications-or-web-push-notifications-for-pwa). As of today it seems that it mainly (always) doesn't work because of the iOS browsers' lack of support for the [Push API](https://caniuse.com/push-api) (likely because Apple wants people to build native apps instead).

Since I still want to continue building a web app I'm looking for alternative ways to solve this requirement/feature (notify the user that something has happened server side even though they don't have the web app active on their screen. This given they do have it open in a browser tab though).

So what is another way to inform a web app user that something has happened server side? I encourage you to think outside the box.

PS. Sort of off topic but my tech stack is NextJS and Firebase (Firestore, Auth, Cloud Messaging)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the app is running in an open tab, how about Server-sent events or WebSockets?

Server-side events: "To enable servers to push data to web pages over HTTP or using dedicated server-push protocols."

Comment: By "open tab", do you mean the tab has to be in the foreground?
Server-sent events sounds interesting. Is that something you've tested or know others that have together with Safari on an iPhone?

Comment: Find an online demo and try it? For example http://express-eventsource.herokuapp.com/

Comment: By open tab I mean that it you are lucky it works in the background for a while but it probably needs to be in the foreground on mobile. This is because radio communication is a big battery drain on mobile.