# PWA push notification on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, safari, progressive-web-apps

I am looking for a way to send and display notifications on ios pwa apps.

I know it is not possible since the ios safari (and non of the other browsers on ios) support neither the push api nor the notification api.

I am wondering if there was a workaround to do that.

I have already taken a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819485/sending-push-notifications-to-ios-from-pwa), but honestly didn't understand at all.

Comment: Any updates on this after ios 15.4 release?

Comment: @NaveenKumar refer to this answer for the latest update. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72899370/12520496

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The truth is NOT for mobile Safari, at the time I write this answer. I am doing a long research... The Apple PWA on Safari increased a lot, but is not comparable to others like Google Chrome browser. As It was said in the [article](https://love2dev.com/pwa/ios/):

> At this point in time Apple's iPhone and iPads do not support native
> push notifications. You can gracefully fallback to SMS notifications.

So, till the moment I have this resume to share:

- Do Progressive Web Apps (PWA) work on iOS? YES...
- Apple may wants to turn the PWA as an alternative to the Apple Store.
- We still can’t open an external link in Safari
- Still can’t use Push Notifications
- There is a 50MB service worker cache limit
- Web apps that have not been used will have their cached assets purged after 7 days

Fonts:[webkit.org](https://webkit.org/),[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit),[brainhub.eu](https://brainhub.eu/library/pwa-on-ios/),[love2dev.com](https://love2dev.com/pwa/ios/),[firt.dev](https://firt.dev/ios-14.5/)

Answer (score 5):

NEW:

Push API is currently in development for Safari (including iOS).  It is not currently finished but should be available for testing in a Safari Technology Preview within the next few months.

OLD:

It is not possible to have Push Notifications on Safari.  It's been brought up many times and has even been a topic of this years WWDC.

See the following threads:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681575

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681748

If developers want push notifications in Safari we'll need to have a much louder voice.  As stated in the link above, native apps got notifications in 2009, it's 2021 and Apple has not even indicated if they are willing to work on it.

Comment: Hey Tony, I stumbled across your answer today and wanted to ask you, if you have any link, providing further informations about Push API making its way to Safari? Cheers, Luke

Comment: @LukasMarschall https://firt.dev/ios-15.4b