# Does FCM support push notification to PWA on iPhone?

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps, push-api

I host a PWA website and I am trying to integrate push notifications to my users who may have the website open in a browser tab even if their phones are inactive.  You notoriously can't send Push notifications to iPhones without using Apple Push Notifications service (APNs).

Seeing as the point of firebase cloud messaging (FCM) is to outsource the message handlers, I kinda assumed it would support sending push notifications to iPhones somehow via APNs, but the information here suggests you still can't do this from the web.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Safari and iPhones don't support Push API.

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576541/2116253

Option #2 may be possible if you know the device ID token, which is apparently very hard to get and perhaps not possible anymore because Apple are trying to make it harder to obtain due to security concerns.

I think the actual sending via APNs from server side is quite easy, the problem comes with the initial setup/registration and actually granting permissions that allow notifications to arrive.

So, in short, I don't mind registering my website with Apple, agreeing to terms and obtaining keys for the purpose of interfacing with APNs, but I don't want to make and distribute a whole native iOS app just to send notifications to devices about my website.

Does anybody know the correct way to achieve this in 2022 ?

Comment: afaik, there is no real way to do that atm. Since I am having the same problem, I am looking into a low-effort way to create a native way with ionic or nativescript

Comment: Any updates - Are PWA push notifications supported on iPhones at least now?

Comment: Web push is now supported on IOS as of version 16.4.1